# Write a callback function in keras so that validation and model get saved at middle of epoch as training data is huge

Tags: tensorflow, keras

During Training a huge data best metric can occur at middle not necessarily at the end of epoch .

Comment: You can just use `steps_per_epoch` in `model.fit` to define how long you want one epoch to be.

Answer (score 0):

First what do you mean by best metric? If you want to save the model with the lowest validation loss you have to wait till the end of an epoch because that is when the validation loss and accuracy is calculated. If you are interested in training accuracy and training loss that is calculated at the end of every batch. Until you run ALL the batches in an epoch you don't know which one has the best performance. In the end you have to process all your data to find the best result. You can use the callback ModelCheckpoint to save the model with the best performance. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/).